# Pop up calendar for date selection in place of input box

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using a macro, in which I am using input box for manually typing date for `.autofilter` The two lines as below.

```
key1 = InputBox("Expiry Date", "Title")
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=key1
```

Here I need and pop up a calendar, so that instead of manually typing date, I can choose a date from calendar.

Comment: See [A Pop-up Calendar for Excel](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Here u can find answer to ur question [link](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm)